# elaticsearch, JAVA_HOME error at ES start, Ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch

I got "JAVA_HOME" error so before exported JAVA_HOME .

bitnami@bitnami-magento-b4b5:/$ export JAVA_HOME=/opt/bitnami/java
bitnami@bitnami-magento-b4b5:/$ export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
bitnami@bitnami-magento-b4b5:/$ $JAVA_HOME
-bash: /opt/bitnami/java: Is a directory

```
bitnami@bitnami-magento-b4b5:/$ sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
bitnami@bitnami-magento-b4b5:/$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-06-09 05:18:40 UTC; 5s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 6548 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6548 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 09 05:18:40 bitnami-magento-b4b5 systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Jun 09 05:18:40 bitnami-magento-b4b5 elasticsearch[6548]: warning: Falling back to java on path. This behavior is deprecated. Specify JAVA_HOME
Jun 09 05:18:40 bitnami-magento-b4b5 elasticsearch[6548]: could not find java; set JAVA_HOME
Jun 09 05:18:40 bitnami-magento-b4b5 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 09 05:18:40 bitnami-magento-b4b5 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 09 05:18:40 bitnami-magento-b4b5 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My java version

```
bitnami@bitnami-magento-b4b5:/$ java -version
 openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

JAVA_HOME path is set is correct?

```
bitnami@bitnami-magento-b4b5:/opt/bitnami/java$ ls -l
total 184
-r--r--r-- 1 root    root   1522 Oct 18  2019 ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root   4096 Apr 22 05:37 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 bitnami root   4096 Apr 29 05:38 bitnami
drwxr-xr-x 9 root    root   4096 Apr 22 05:37 lib
-r--r--r-- 1 root    root  19274 Oct 18  2019 LICENSE
-r--r--r-- 1 root    root 148619 Oct 18  2019 THIRD_PARTY_README
```

Where i can find logs? 
I checked :

1
/var/log/elasticsearch# ls -l
total 0

2
root@bitnami-magento-b4b5:/# locate elasticsearch.log
/opt/bitnami/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log  - this file is empty.

Comment: Does the **root** user have the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` set? You are using `sudo`, so it will look for the `JAVA_HOME` for the root user.

Comment: now i check "sudo su > export JAVA_HOME... > systemctl start elasticsearch.service" and the same thing.

Comment: You need to export the `JAVA_HOME` in the profile of the root user using the files `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, you can also set it globaly editting the file `/etc/environment` and adding the `JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java` line.

Comment: i exported JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment but this did not help